# How to perform the same action on all the data frames made by the split function in R

Tags: r, split

I have a data frame that has a bunch of columns and my end goal is to rank hospitals by one of the columns in each state. I have used the split function to make separate data frames for each state, but now I want to manipulate all of those data frames in the same way. I could write 50 lines of code, but that would not be very efficient.

So to be clear, my question is when I use the split function to split 1 data frame into many data frames, how do I repeat the same action on each data frame? See below for the code:

```
rankall <- function(outcome, num = "best") 
  {
  chart <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")
  
 if(!outcome %in% c("heart attack" , "heart failure" , "pneumonia")){
    stop("invalid outcome")
  } else {
    keys <- c("heart attack" = 11, "heart failure" = 17, "pneumonia" = 23)
    outcomeKey <- keys[outcome]
  }
  
  chart2 <- chart[, c(2, outcomeKey)]
  chart2[,2] <- apply(chart2[,2, drop = F], 2, function(x) as.numeric(x))

  test <- split(chart2, chart$State)
  
  }
```

If I were to input View(test[["AL"]]), I would see the Alabama specific data frame. I could repeat this with all the other states.

Comment: Use `lapply()` to apply whatever function you like to each data.frame in that list. Just make sure the function accepts a data.frame as input.

Comment: 1) `chart2[,2] <- apply(chart2[,2, drop = F], 2, function(x) as.numeric(x))` doesn't seem correct. If you want to convert only one column to numeric you can do `chart2[[2]] <- as.numeric(chart2[[2]])`. You don't need `apply`. 2) You could arrange the data first by state and the other column and then split the data.  3) It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @RonakShah I have tried doing it your way but it does not work. Thank you for the tip though, I will put a reproducible example next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I eventually found out is that when you use the split function to make multiple data frames, each data frame is assigned an index value. In this particular case I can call one of those indices by:

```
test[[1]] ## will give the first data frame produced by the split function
```

With this being the case, you can then use a for loop to apply something to every data frame. In my particular example I have 54 data frames so just as an example you could do the following:

```
df <-   df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = 54))
for (i in 1:54)
{
  df[i , 1] <- mean(test[[i]][,1])
}
```

This for loop would go through evert data frame and then add that to a different row in the initialized data frame. This is not what I needed to do in my particular example and I am not sure if this is even correct syntax but its just to show how you can use the split function efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to rank your data by a column named `column_var`, you could try something like:

```
lapply(test, function(x) x[order(x$column_var),])  # rank in increasing order
```

or

```
lapply(test, function(x) x[order(x$column_var, decreasing = TRUE),]) # for decreasing order
```